# SOUNDEX() и LIKE в SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Функция `SOUNDEX()`:
Клиент `Kids Place` находится в таблице `Customers`, и его контактным лицом является `Michael Green`. Но что если это опечатка? и на самом деле контактное лицо пишется как `Michelle Green`? Очевидно, поиск по корректному имени ничего не даст, как показано ниже:

```
SELECT cust_name, cust_contact FROM Customers WHERE cust_contact = 'Michael Green';
```

Вывод не покажет не одну запись (строку).

```
cust_name          cust_contact
------------------------------------
```

А теперь попробуем выполнить поиск с помощью функции `SOUNDEX()`, чтобы найти все имена контактных лиц, которые звучат как `Michael Green`.

```
SELECT cust_name, cust_contact FROM Customers WHERE SOUNDEX(cust_contact) = SOUNDEX('Michael Green');

cust_name                  cust_contact
----------------------------------------

Kids Place                 Michelle Green
```

Теперь вопрос:  чем отличается от `WHERE Customers LIKE '%Green'` и тому подобное? Зачем нам `SOUNDEX()` если есть `LIKE`? Если сделать LIKE с 2 символами мол первое слово начинается на M, а второй на G, в чем тогда отличие?

Comment: тем, что `LIKE` найдёт *Anton Green*, если таковой имеется, а `SOUNDEX` - нет.

Comment: @ArchDemon а если сделать LIKE с 2 символами мол первое слово начинается на M, а второй на G, в чем тогда отличие?

Comment: _первое слово начинается на M, а второй на G_ - Тогда найдёт, например, `Mother of God`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov получается никак нельзя сделать запрос с SOUNDEX() чтобы он выдал такие же результаты, как если бы мы использовали LIKE?

Comment: Наоборот: с помощью LIKE не всегда можно сделать запрос, который повторит SOUNDEX.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хорошо, спасибо